# C++ How to animate ("slide") controls from point A to point B?

Tags: c++, winapi

I display a list of custom panels beneath one another. When the user drags one of those panels out of the list, the panels below should move to fill the gap. No problem so far.

Now I'd like to animate this movement. This code works fine, but doesn't quite do what I want, because the panels still kinda "jump" to their new position. (AnimateWindow only uses the height of `pControl` and scrolls it in from nothing. That looks weird if the distance between old and new position is much larger than the height.)

```
TWinControl * pControl = some_panel_from_my_list;
pControl->Visible = false;

pControl->Top  = new_top;
pControl->Left = new_left;

AnimateWindow( pControl->Handle, 200, AW_SLIDE | AW_VER_NEGATIVE );
pControl->Visible = true;
```

Is there some variant of this to just say: "Slide this control from point A to B?"

Google turned up either empty or with too many unrelated hits, and all I find here is iOS or jQuery related... I hope that someone here can point me in the right direction. Thanks!

**Edit:**
I'm not set on using `AnimateWindow`--- I know that can't do what I want. I'm asking for alternatives that do. Just found `UIAnimationManager` which looks promising (and overkill), but I'll need to investigate that further. Implementing my own timer-based animation would be a last resort, because seriously--- such an animation is so normal nowadays I'd be more than surprised if WinAPI doesn't cover it!

Comment: AnimateWindow only creates special effects when changing a window's visibility. It does nothing for the window's position. You would need to write code that changes the window's position (i.e., calls SetWindowPos) in response to a timer.

Comment: To read more about possible ways to solve this problem, see for instance [this community wiki answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1294828/824425).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WIN32, C++: Is it possible to animate a window without hiding it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282452/win32-c-is-it-possible-to-animate-a-window-without-hiding-it)

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "kinda jump"?

Comment: @QPaysTaxes `AnimateWindows` uses a default vertical distance for the animation (the height of `pControl`), regardless of the distance between the old and new positions. So if I have a deltaY of 200px but `pControl` is only 40px high, the control jumps for 160px and is then scrolling in from nothing.

Comment: @Robin Now edit that into your question where it says "kinda jump" :)

Comment: Well, you can be surprised then. The Windows API doesn't offer built-in support for this type of animation. It is relatively common now, but wasn't when the API was designed. Arguably it should not be as common as it is now, most people abuse special effects and sacrifice usability in the process. (Certainly do not forget to query `SPI_GETCLIENTAREAANIMATION` and respect the user's wishes not to see these animations.) I don't know why you see a timer as a "last resort", that is the *standard* way to implement this in Windows. Use the buffered painting APIs (Vista+) for an even smoother effect.

Comment: @CodyGray This would actually be an _answer_ to my question ("Is there some variant of this to just say: Slide this control from point A to B?"). Not the one I was hoping for, but still. If you post your comment as an answer, I'll accept it. And then do the timer implementation... -_-  "Last resort" because I try to avoid reimplementing stuff when there's an API function for it...